# Flex wrap with elastic children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list element on the page that expands on hover, it is expected that this element will rarely be displayed solo and there will be enough of them that it will wrap on to multiple lines.

The problem rears its head when the hovered element is the last item in a row before the line gets wrapped.

[image: visual of the problem]

as you can see when the element expands on hover it starts to automatically get wrapped and there lies my problem.

```
.tag div {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tag:hover div {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 61px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I am looking for a CSS solution but if the consensus is that only JS can help then I will readily concede.

Cheers!

Comment: When you hover over the element it has some extra buttons displayed hence the element becomes wider and wraps to the next line. The simplest solution in my understanding would be to always show these extra buttons as I don't think there is a solution to preserve the space and to not wrap.

Comment: thanks @Morpheus that's the solution I am coming to accept as well

Comment: Is there a situation where the element's width is smaller than the increased width caused by hover? If not, I might have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the increased width (caused by hover) is always smaller than the width of the original element (before hover), we can simply adjust its container to add padding. Having this padding, the container element can ensure that the above behaviour (that is: an element wrapping to the next line because of added width) does not happen. This added padding's value is the exact value of the increased width value. The added padding is removed when a chip is being hovered (thus, allowing it to expand nicely) and added back when no chip is being hovered. This works nicely to ensure that expansion can always happen without an element wrapping to the next line.

Running on a container's width of `1567px`, I tried the below code and it works just fine. Try disabling the JS code and adjust the margin such that the last element (`chip`) on the first line wraps to the second row upon hover. Then, try enabling the JS code again. Here's the code:

```js
const hoverWidthIncrease = (() => {
  let aChip = document.querySelector('.chip')
  let aChipExpand = aChip.querySelector('.chip--buttons')
  let beforeExpandWidth = aChip.getBoundingClientRect().width
  let afterExpandWidth
  
  aChipExpand.style.display = 'inline' // Or whatever display it has
  afterExpandWidth = aChip.getBoundingClientRect().width
  aChipExpand.style.display = ''
  return afterExpandWidth - beforeExpandWidth
})()
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const chips = document.querySelectorAll('.chip')

container.style.paddingRight = `${hoverWidthIncrease}px`
chips.forEach(chip => {
  chip.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    container.style.paddingRight = '0px'
  })
  
  chip.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    container.style.paddingRight = `${hoverWidthIncrease}px`
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .75rem;  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.chip {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #08112e;
  color: white;
}

.chip--buttons {
  color: #FFDDDDEE;
  display: none;
}

.chip:hover .chip--buttons {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name asd <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name wefasd <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name asdfwew <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name asdf <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name asdfg <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name asdgcxz <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name jgh <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name ert <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name fghk <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name vbnm <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
  <div class = "chip">Tag Name vbnmg <span class = "chip--buttons">Expand</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:
Put buttons as absolute position relative to your tag container and they can be visible there or be visible on hover. This might need some extra padding to accommodate buttons on right top corner

That way these things will happen:

1. Your container will not expand, thus wrapping will stay put.
2. Your buttons gets displayed when they are hovered
3. UX will get increased and non obstructing

Harder solution:
Put your tag container absolute to its parent container when it's hovered. Pop out the tag and expand it over existing tags. Fill in it's space with blank space so other tags do not wrap back empty space.

This method is more complex and kinda ugly.
Another semi simple method would be to pre occupy buttons space with padding or margin and compensate it on hover while button appears. Either way structure of inline tags would change to make it more accessible.